# How to not include the text of a child when writing a CSS expression

Tags: java, html, css, selenium

Here is the HTML for an element on my page. This element has text listing the user name, followed by a logout link

```
<div class="NavUserText">
 User: Automation User of Awesomeness
   <a class="LogoutText" onclick="logout(); return false;" title="Logout" href="logout">Logout</a>
</div>
```

I want to find a CSS expression that will only include the text "User: Automation User of Awesomeness"

If I use the below expression, it includes the text I want, along with the text of the child; "User: Automation User of Awesomeness Logout"

```
div.NavUserText
```

Is there a way to edit the CSS expression so the text "Logout" is excluded? I'm not familiar with the negation pseudo-class, but I tried the below CSS expression, which did not work. It returned no text instead of excluding Logout.

```
div.NavUserText :not(.LogoutText)
```

----------  Attional Information Added  ---------------
[image]

The HTML listed will select this entire element. I am using Java and Selenium for element verification. Logout is a link, and I can use the below CSS. This will allow me to only select the link, so I can click it, and verify that it says "Logout"

```
a.LogoutText
```

In my program, the text User: Automation User of Awesomeness" will change for each user that I log in with. What I want to do is create an object using CSS that will only select/return this text. Is there a way to do this? I can't seem to get the user text separated from the logout text. The CSS I use will return "User: Automation User of Awesomeness Logout" instead of only "User: Automation User of Awesomeness".

Comment: CSS does not select text, it selects elements (tags). Can you describe the desired selection target in terms of tags? No. So CSS can't select it. What it *can* do is select the .NavUserText and do something, and also select the .LogoutText and do something else (including undoing the first something). Or of course insert an element whose only content is the text in question.

Comment: So you want cascading style sheets that don't cascade? ;) Perhaps you should instead wrap the username in a `span` with a special class you can easily select.

Comment: ..and yet another example of why text should always be in text tags. Bare text nodes are very hard to select,

Comment: Casey Falk is correct, don't reinvent the wheel. Wrap your text in a span then select the span.

Comment: While this is not CSS, you can achieve this with jQuery easily:

 $(".NavUserText")
    .clone()    
    .children() 
    .remove()   
    .end()  
    .text();

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, but I realized that I did not include enough information. I am writing an automated test, and need to verify the text of an element. I won't be able to modify the html for this application.